Using the preposition 'to' for describing the relationship between nouns in the structure: "Like noun 'to' noun"
I wrote some similes using the preposition 'to', but then I was advised to switch it for the preposition 'in' so that it would "make more sense".
I realized that I'm not too sure where I saw this format from and I wondered if it was even a valid way of structuring the sentence.
The format was: "Like noun 'to' noun", which I could attach either to the start or end of a clause. I used this format to
describe the relationship between the two nouns.
Some examples:

The cat navigated the crowd fluidly like fish to water.


So light was her dress that it lifted like feather to wind.

The suggestion would modify these into:

Like fish in water.


Like feather in wind.

I also realize that the preposition could be potentially switched for other words, from...

Like flint to steel, an idea flashed in his head.


Like fire to fuel, the rumors spread.

To:

Like flint and steel.


Like fire with fuel.

Of course, I could use more descriptive words, such as "flint against steel" or "fire following fuel", but my question is about the validity of using the preposition 'to'.
In my head, I think I interpreted the 'to' being short for: "Like noun (in relation) to noun", or even "Like noun (put) to noun"; simply to mean an instance where an
object interacts with another. And the "Like noun 'to' noun" format alone doesn't elaborate on that interaction as the clause it's attached to already reveals the nature of the interaction (the simile).
So, does the format "Like noun 'to' noun" have precedence as a creative style or is it a bad habit to structure the sentence this way? Would I be better
off using different words like 'in', 'with', 'and' rather than 'to' so I can describe the relationship between nouns?
I apologize if I don't explain my question very well.
03/10/24 edit: No changes made to the original post. The clarifying comments and answers are greatly appreciated; thank you! :)

"She took to it like a fish to water" is a common expression, relating to the phrasal verb "take to X" ("like a fish takes to water"). You should normally use the regular preposition in such structures, and generally use articles except before mass nouns. I think you've invented a special grammatical structure when normally you just want the normal grammar.

We use "to" when we describe analogies as "A is to B as X is to Y". But in other contexts, we just use whatever preposition fits the situation.

@Barmar I've seen such not-quite-metaphors called 'proportionalities', as with the classic statement of ratios. 'God will answer persevering supplications just as surely as the unrighteous judge in time acceded to the widow's cry for justice' [paraphrase of Luke 18:1ff]: a metaphor would compare God to the unrighteous judge, which would be laughable.

The verb in your sentences  is a primary  factor governing the choice of preposition in such comparisons.  Erase this construction with "to" from your memory banks.  The verb restricts the choice of preposition.  E.g. She navigated through the crowd      She navigated through the crowd like a knife through butter, like wind through late-autumn trees, whatever.

Like Barmar, I suspect you got this idea from patterns we use for a different kind of comparison, analogies. Students taking the SAT test are familiar with this pattern, "A is to B as C is to D," also represented as "A : B :: C : D." For example, "cow is to herd as goose is to gaggle." In this case, "is to" can be read as "has the same relation to."
Of course, this isn't simile. We are comparing and drawing connections, but a cow is not "like" a herd or like a goose.
Much fuss is made over similes, often in grade-school poetry class, but there's not really all that much to them. The only linguistic pattern is the use of words like "like" or "as." The surrounding words continue to follow the usual semantic patterns that make sense.
Thus, you could use "to" if it matches a usage in your comparison:

He addressed himself to his dinner like a gambler to his cards—calmly, coolly, but with a methodical and thorough focus.
He ran to her like a horse to the stable.

But when "to" doesn't fit naturally in the sentence, there's no reason to use it. You could parallel other prepositions:

He worked his way through the book like a miner through a vein of rich ore.

... but you're not even obliged to do that:

The cavalry tore through the opposing army as an awl penetrates leather.

For that matter, we're under no obligation to even set up such "A/B/C/D" sets. We can have a simile with as little as "She swam like a fish."

To elaborate on StuartF's comment, in which he (correctly, I think) explains how you might have come to think that this "to" structure would work...
It is not a relationship between nouns. The simile applies to the verb phrase in your sentence, and so you must consider the appropriate preposition(s) to use in the verb phrase as they will be used  in the simile.
Rumor spreads through a village, a town, a city, a network.

Rumor spread like fire through dry brush.

And prepositions can be combined:
Oil on the surface of a body of water spreads across it.

A smile spread across the con-man's face like oil on a pond.

